# Why flex-shrink doesn't work in inline-flex

Tags: flexbox, inline, shrink

Why items dont shrink in inline-flex. But it works fine in normal flex. Maybe it is supposed to work that way, I dont know. Maybe it is somewhere in the spec but I coudn't find anything related. I would be grateful if someone could explain this.

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  margin 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.inline-flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inline-flex">
    <div class="item">no-shrink</div>
    <div class="item">no-shrink</div>
    <div class="item">no-shrink</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="item">shrink</div>
    <div class="item">shrink</div>
    <div class="item">shrink</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: As far as what I've observed, `flex` acts like a `block` to it's surroundings and `inline-flex` acts like an `inline-block` to it's surroundings , but their children behave the same. I never noticed the shrinking anomaly before...

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, `flex` acts like a `block` and `inline-flex` like `inline-block` on the outside and their children behave identically. The flex-items `.item` are acting totally different when they should appear the same because their behavior is influenced by the flex-container (`.flex` and `.inline-flex`). Aside from the flex-containers having different `display` values, there are no other differences.

- Each `.item` of `.inline-flex` has retained it's width of 50px
- Each `.item` of `.flex` has a width of 34.6687px

I still haven't figured out why this is but I have 3 different solutions:

`.container` is too small, increase it's width.

*See **Example A***

**Figure I**

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
/* Increase .container to at least the .offsetWidth of the 3 .item`s */
```

Change the `flex` properties of `.item`s or assign `min-width`

*See **Example B***

**Figure II**

```css
.B .item {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  /* OR */
  /* min-width: 50px */
}
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.A {
  width: 200px;
}

.inline-flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.B .item {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  /* OR */
  /* min-width: 50px */
}

h3 {
  margin: 0 0 4px 0
}
```

```html
<h3>OP</h3>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inline-flex">
    <div class="item">XXX XXX</div>
    <div class="item">XXX XXX</div>
    <div class="item">XXX XXX</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="item">XXX XXX</div>
    <div class="item">XXX XXX</div>
    <div class="item">XXX XXX</div>
  </div>
</div>
<h3>Example A</h3>
<div class="container A">
  <div class="inline-flex">
    <div class="item">XXX XXX</div>
    <div class="item">XXX XXX</div>
    <div class="item">XXX XXX</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="item">XXX XXX</div>
    <div class="item">XXX XXX</div>
    <div class="item">XXX XXX</div>
  </div>
</div>
<h3>Example B</h3>
<div class="container B">
  <div class="inline-flex">
    <div class="item">XXX XXX</div>
    <div class="item">XXX XXX</div>
    <div class="item">XXX XXX</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="item">XXX XXX</div>
    <div class="item">XXX XXX</div>
    <div class="item">XXX XXX</div>
  </div>
</div>
```